# Is there a way to shorthand this CASE statement in Snowflake/SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Have this case statement here that I want to use with both "CASE WHEN" and CASE ILIKE" similar to below:

```
SELECT
  CASE coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+)(\/|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)), random_sample_column)
     when 'green' then 'GO'
     when 'red' then 'STOP'
     when 'yellow' then 'SLOW'
     else
         case when coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+) ilike '%green' then 'GO?'
         case when coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+) ilike '%yellow' then 'SLOW?'
         case when coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+) ilike '%red' then 'STOP?'     
   END as sample_derived_column
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME;
```

Is there a way to write the (NESTED) ilike case statements similar to the 'Shorthand' being used in the 'CASE WHEN' statements at the top of the code block?

Thanks in advance!

Sample data here:

```
random_sample_column
--------------
yellow30-1123$%schmidt
jingle43123heimer
red
isthelightgreen
beluw
beow
blue
```

Comment: Some explanation as to how those example strings should map to specific values would be nice. Also, please include both sample data and expected output in the question (my bad for not being clear earlier). Make sure the sample data is representative of your actual data so that we don't miss any obvious edge cases

Comment: I am using a wildcard search as demonstrated above in the query :) To be honest the only part I am unsure of is if there was a way i can use ILIKE similar to how I am using the other CASE WHEN statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use column aliases:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,
  coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+)(\/|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)), random_sample_column) AS helper_col1,
  coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+') AS helper_col2,
  CASE helper_col1
     when 'green' then 'GO'
     when 'red' then 'STOP'
     when 'yellow' then 'SLOW'
     else
         case when helper_col2 ilike '%green' then 'GO?'
              when helper_col2 ilike '%yellow' then 'SLOW?'
              when helper_col2 ilike '%red' then 'STOP?' 
         end    
   END as sample_derived_column
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME
)
SELECT * EXCLUDE (helper_col1, helper_col2)
FROM cte;
```

---

Nesting is not readable so:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,
  coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+)(\/|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)), random_sample_column) AS helper_col1,
  coalesce(lower(regexp_substr(random_sample_column, '\/key_word\/\\d+\/([\\w-]+') AS helper_col2,
  CASE
     when helper_col1 =  'green'      then 'GO'
     when helper_col1 = 'red'         then 'STOP'
     when helper_col1 = 'yellow'      then 'SLOW'
     when helper_col2 ilike '%green'  then 'GO?'
     when helper_col2 ilike '%yellow' then 'SLOW?'
     when helper_col2 ilike '%red'    then 'STOP?'       
   END as sample_derived_column
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME
)
SELECT * EXCLUDE (helper_col1, helper_col2)
FROM cte;
```

---

**EDIT:**

In order to perform the simple case expression with `LIKE` predicate and wildcard:

```
SELECT 
   CASE expresssion
     WHEN ILIKE '%green' THEN 'GO?'
     WHEN ILIKE '%yellow' THEN 'SLOW?'
     WHEN ILIKE '%red' THEN 'STOP?'
   END 
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME;
```

the used SQL dialect has to implement optional `SQL:2003 Extended CASE expression(F262)` feature.

More at: [SQL 'CASE WHEN x' vs. 'CASE x WHEN' with greater-than condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930099/5070879)

Comment: Thanks Lukasz! What if we don't want to use column aliases? Probably not possible right?

Comment: @JohnWick The `simple case` uses `=` as comparison operator. In the ELSE part you are aiming for `ILIKE ` with wildcard  and for that you need to use `searched case`.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz.  Sorry to ask but would you be able to show me please? :) (```searched case```)

Comment: @JohnWick  Already did it  in the answer. There is no syntax for `CASE expression WHEN '%value% THEN ...` and it is written as `CASE WHEN expression LIKE '%value%'  THEN ...`

Comment: AH sorry about that i wasn't sure Lukasz. Appreciate the help!